# After running Kompose I get: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, kompose

#### Whats the Problem?

I can't get my pods running which are using a volume. In the Kubernetes Dashboard I got the following error:

> running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "influxdb-6979bff6f9-hpf89": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

#### What did I do?

After running `Kompose convert` to my `docker-compose.yml` file I tried to start the pods with `micro8ks kubectl apply -f .` (I am using micro8ks) I had to replace the version of the networkpolicy yaml files with `networking.k8s.io/v1` (see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/issues/1238#issuecomment-593867095)) but except of this change, I didn't change anything.

#### YAML Files

**influxdb-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: influxdb
  name: influxdb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: influxdb
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/cloud-net: "true"
        io.kompose.network/default: "true"
        io.kompose.service: influxdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: INFLUXDB_HTTP_LOG_ENABLED
          value: "false"
        image: influxdb:1.8
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: influxdb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/influxdb
          name: influx
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: influx
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: influx
status: {}
```

**influxdb-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: ./kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: influxdb
  name: influxdb
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8087"
    port: 8087
    targetPort: 8086
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: influxdb
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**influx-persistenvolumeclaim.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: influx
  name: influx
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PersistentVolumeClaim` will be unbound if either the cluster does not have a `StorageClass` which can dynamically provision a `PersistentVolume` or it does not have a manually created `PersistentVolume` to satisfy the `PersistentVolumeClaim`

Here is a [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) on how to configure a pod to use `PersistentVolume`

To solve the current scenario you can manually create a PV

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Please note usage of `hostPath` is only as an example. It's not recommended for production usage. Consider using external block or file storage from the supported types [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes)

Comment: I created `influx-volume.yaml` with the text you post above and inserted in the `influx-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml` the following: `storageClassName: manual` as descriped in your guide, it seems to work now but I don't understand why `Kompose` does not do this automatically as it seems to be mandatory. I will try to figure out what's about that `StorageClass`, probably the best solution is to be found here.